# Prove the following polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb Z_5[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

> Prove the following polynomials are irreducible over $\mathbb Z_5[x]$:
>   $2x^3+x^2+4x+1$ and $x^4+1$.

So the exponents are already as reduced as they can be in terms of $\mathbb Z_5$. I cannot find any rational roots by factoring or using the rational root test. I don't believe I can't use Eisenstein's criterion on the first polynomial, the second polynomial concludes irreducibility over $\mathbb Q$. Can I then conclude that since no rational roots can be found that they are irreducible over $\mathbb Z_5$?

EDIT: Using N.S.'s advice I will use $a(x)=2x^3+x^2+4x+1$ where $x=0,-1,1,-2,2$ which all give numbers other than zero, thus there are no roots in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$.

Comment: Irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ does not imply irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}_5$. For example $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ but factors as $(x - 2)(x+2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Answer (score 3):

Since you work over $\mathbb Z_5$, rational root test is useless.

For the first one, since it has degree 3, it is irreducible if and only if it doesn't have roots. And there are only 5 possible roots in $\mathbb Z_5$, try them.

For the second, note that
$$X^4+1=X^4-4$$

Comment: Since $x^4-4= (x^2-2)(x^2+2)$ doesn't that make this polynomial reducible? Should I go further and say $(x^2+2)(x^2-2)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_5[x]$?

Comment: @KMath Exactly, it is reducible. Now what you mean by the last statement is that each of $X^2-2$ and $X^2+2$ are irreducible.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ is not a field, hence it does not make sense to discuss the irreducibility or reducibility of those polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$. On the other hand $\mathbb{F}_5$ **is** a field. $x^4+1=\Phi_8(x)$ **factors over any finite field**. In the $\mathbb{F}_5$ case we have
$$ x^4+1 = (x^2-2)(x^2+2) $$
and $x^2\pm 2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$ since $\pm 2$ is not a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{5}$.
In order to prove that $2x^3+x^2-x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$ it is enough to prove it has no linear factors, i.e. no roots in $\mathbb{F}_5$. $0$ is not a root and if $x\in\mathbb{F}_5^*$ we either have $x^2=1$ or $x^2-1$. In the former case
$$2x^3+x^2-x+1 = 2x+1-x+1 = x+2 \neq 0, $$
in the latter case
$$2x^3+x^2-x+1 = -2x-1-x+1 = -3x \neq 0 $$
and we are done.